# Is there a way to implement Stack Navigation inside view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am creating a basic React Native app for my class and I ran into a problem. I am trying to implement the Stack Navigation in my view, but it is not showing the blue stack buttons for some reason. Is it possible to do it this way ?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from '../views/Home.js'

let stack = createStackNavigator();

class Account extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container} >
                <Text style = {styles.PageHeader}>TRENDZ</Text>
                <Text style = {styles.PageSubHeader}> Online Store</Text>
                <Image style = {styles.AccImage} source={require('../../assets/login/login.jpg')} {...this.props} />
                        <stack.Navigator>
                            <stack.Screen name = 'Home' component = {Home} />
                        </stack.Navigator>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    AccImage: {
        height:600,
        width: null
    },
    PageHeader: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 70,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'orange'
    },
    PageSubHeader: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 25,
        paddingBottom: 20
    }
})

export default Account;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible. You can only create the `Stack.Navigator` in your navigator file.
You create your `Stack.Navigator` in your navigator file and then call the screen you want to go inside `Àccount` with `this.props.navigation.navigate('Name of the screen you want to navigate')`.

Waiting for your feedback Thx :). Any doubt please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was wondering why I couldn't put Navigator inside View. Any idea why ?

Comment: You're welcome! It doesn't work because the component ```<Stack.Navigator/>``` was made to only to work in the components where you "register" the screens the app is going to have, where usually you put your ```Navigation.Container```. You can see more details in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) of react navigation.